# ActiveMQ Artemis performance loss

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I have an app to send and receive messages (simplified). With these routes when you send an HTTP request to `http://0.0.0.0:8089/put-message` a JMS message is then sent to `my-queue`, and then when an HTTP request is sent to `http://0.0.0.0:8089/get-message` Camel tries to consume a JMS message from `my-queue` and return the body of that message to the HTTP client:

```xml
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <bean id="artemisConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <argument index="0" value="${jms.url}"/>
        <argument index="1" value="${jms.username}"/>
        <argument index="2" value="${jms.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxSessionsPerConnection" value="500"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="artemisConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8089/put-message"/>
            <inOnly uri="jms:my-queue"/>
        </route>
        <route >
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8089/get-message"/>
            <pollEnrich timeout="0">
                <simple>jms:queue:my-queue</simple>
            </pollEnrich>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Stack:

- ActiveMQ Artemis 2.25
- Camel 2.23.2
- Karaf 4.2
- messaginghub/pooled-jms 1.0.6
- artemis-jms-client-osgi 2.7.0

I am doing load testing (Apache Bench 5kb messages, 100 threads for sending and 100 threads for receiving), and I observe the following. The service works for half an hour without problems (queue does not increase in size), but then the time for receiving messages from the queue increases. I was able to reduce some metrics and noticed that it increases oldGen (at the same time, the queue has not yet left in the PAGE mode).

Based on the recommendation in the [ActiveMQ Artemis tuning documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tuning.html#tuning-the-vm) `XX:+UseParallelOldGC` was used when starting the broker, but even if you set another mode the behavior does not change.

Here is a screenshot of memory utilization from the JVM where the broker is running:

[image: you can see the increase in oldgen]

[image: this picture shows pollenrich time]

You can see how the time to receive messages from the queue increases. However, it's worth noting that if you use permanent consumers (there is no re-creation of connections aka `<from uri="jms:queue:my-queue" />`) then the work is stable.

What could be the reason for the increase memory oldgen?

What other metrics can I apply to deal with the problem?

**UPD**: heap dump (when performance loss)

[image]

**UPD 2**: and heap dump(when i use Performance Tools ./artemis perf client --message-size 5000 --persistent queue://TEST_QUEUE) - no leak

[image]

Comment: 1. only broker
2. I used the advice from https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tuning.html , if you set another mode, the behavior does not change
3.  paging to disk
4. yes, get-message - connects and receives one message
there is one observation - if you use permanent consumers (there is no re-creation of connections aka <from uri="jms:queue:my-queue" />) - the work is stable

Comment: You say that the, "queue does not increase in size," but then later you essentially say that the queue's address is paging messages to disk. The address won't page messages to disk unless the queues on that address cause it to exceed the configured `max-size-bytes` so the queue size would have to increase at some point. Do you have any screenshots which correlate memory use with the size of the address or queue?

Comment: In your configuration you've defined `pooledConnectionFactory`. Is that not being used by the routes for their connections?

Comment: When you reference "permanent consumers" how are those configured?

Comment: i create dump 30m, i see ParallelGCFailedAllocation(attached to topic)

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a heap dump. It looks like just a screenshot/recording of GC activity. A heap dump would be the entire contents of memory that could be parsed and analyzed to see exactly what was consuming space.

Comment: Any feedback on my previous questions?

Comment: i captured heap dump and uploaded it to gdisk

Comment: Looking through the heap dump, the most memory by far is being consumed by the messages in a queue named `soap-connector-rt-test`. I don't see anything particularly noteworthy. It seems like your consumer just needs to keep pace with your producer.

Comment: During the captured of the dump, queue was empty

Comment: According to the heap dump the queue was not empty. What metric were you observing that indicated the queue was empty?

Comment: Also, I still don't understand how "permanent consumers" are configured and how the pooled connection factory is being used. If the pooled connection factory was being used properly I don't see how "permanent consumers" would make much difference, but you say the problem goes a way when using "permanent consumers."

Comment: for counting i used jolokia method countMessages()
permanent consumer - so I call which constantly receive messages from the queue, and in my case, a new consumer (connection and sessions reused messaginghub/pooled-jms) is created for each http-request, receives one message and closes

Comment: i added upd2 - the difference is more than noticeable, what is io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentUnpooledUnfafeHeapByteBuf.array ?

Comment: `io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentUnpooledUnfafeHeapByteBuf` is an implementation of `io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf` which is used by `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQBuffer`.

Comment: Hey Justin @JustinBertram . I have some news regarding my problem. I managed to avoid an memory leak thanks to the consumerWindowSize parameter. I think the problem is in the default buffer (as I found out from the description https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html). I wrote a little app for you so you can see the memory leak problem for yourself. https://github.com/tim08/camel-artemis-leak

Comment: @JustinBertram i set consumerWindowSize = 0 in my main project, if you have any questions I will be happy to answer them

Comment: @bare37, thanks for the update. I had basically given up on this as Stack Overflow is ill suited for this level of back-and-forth. I looked at the app you created, but I still don't have a way to apply a load to it and reproduce the problem. If you suspect there's a bug in the broker or the core client you're probably better off [opening a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS) or working via the [ActiveMQ users mailing list](https://activemq.apache.org/contact) (or even Slack).

Comment: Any news here? I didn't see any new Jiras or email threads related to this. Did you resolve the problem?